# Water boiling with salt and without it

Tags: aqueous-solution

Does 1L of water with salt boil faster or slower than one with the same amount of water but without salt?
What I know is that since when you add salt to the water the temperature of boiling increase than the water with salt with take longer.

Comment: The rate of boiling is dependent on heat influx

Comment: What doe you mean with “boil faster”? E.g. reaching boiling temperature faster starting from room temperature, or evaporating faster to dryness?

Comment: Loong: reaching boiling temperature faster starting from room temperature

Answer (score 2):

If the heat applied is equal than yes, 1 L of salt water boil slower than 1 L of unsalted water.

If you are intrested you can calculate the diference in boiling point with the formula $\Delta T = K\ b\ i$, where $i$ is the Van't Hoff factor, (2 for the salt NaCl), and $K$ is the ebuliocopic constant of water ($0.512\ \mathrm{^\circ C\ kg\ mol^{-1}}$), and $b$ is the molality of solution.

Comment: Thank you! Yes the same amount of heat is applied.